# vulkano how to create uniform buffer

Tags: rust, vulkan

I was wondering how to create and bind a uniform buffer. The Vulkan tutorial uses `CpuAccessibleBuffer`, but it seems to no longer be a thing. The teapot example on the Vulkano repo uses another way which seems too complex. What is the easiest way to create and bind a uniform buffer?

```
use cgmath::Matrix4;

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
#[repr(C)]
pub struct MyUniformBuffer {
    pub projection : Matrix4<f32>,
    pub modelview : Matrix4<f32>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The teapot example is the way to go. But it's not that complicated! :)

Since the content of uniform buffers usually change between draw calls, you need to have a buffer for each of the draw calls in the command queue. OpenGL hides this detail from you, Vulkan doesn't. It's not always easy to tell ahead how many of these uniform buffers need to exist simultaneously at any point in time: it depends on the swapchain, how many times you render a given object etc.

For static GPU resources (like a vertex buffer) one could use a simple `Buffer::from_iter`. But in the case of uniform buffers, that would give you subpar performance due to reallocation in each frame.

Vulkano offers a buffer pool called [`SubbufferAllocator`](https://docs.rs/vulkano/latest/vulkano/buffer/allocator/struct.SubbufferAllocator.html) to solve this issue. It manages the lifetime of buffers for you: you request a buffer from the pool, and after rendering the buffer goes back to the pool.

In a nutshell:

- You create a `SubbufferAllocator` once using [SubbufferAllocator::new](https://docs.rs/vulkano/latest/vulkano/buffer/allocator/struct.SubbufferAllocator.html#method.new).
- In each frame, you request a new buffer (called `Subbuffer` in Vulkano) and upload your uniform values like so:

```rust
// Calculate uniform buffer values
let data = // ...

// Allocate buffer
let subbuffer = my_subbuffer_allocator.allocate_sized()?;

// Write data to buffer
*buffer.write()? = data;
```

Then you bind the buffer as a regular descriptor set:

```rust
WriteDescriptorSet::buffer(binding, buffer)
```

The teapot example has a bit of cruft, but the idea is relatively simple. For really small uniform structs (up to 128 bytes), you could use `layout(push_constant)` instead, it doesn't need a buffer, see the `push-constants` example.